# How to remotely deploy a war file on JBoss AS 7?

Tags: jboss, war

How would I go about remotely deploying a war file on JBoss Application Server 7?

I've uploaded the war file to the application server and tried using :
**http://[IP]:9990/[war file name ]**  in a browser but the path is not found.

IP: The server IP address

Comment: How did you upload the WAR to the server? Via the web console or maven plugin?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins via web browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL that you need to be using is `http://[IP]:8080/[war file name ]`. The port 9990 is admin port for deploying the war file but by default the application is accessible through port 8080.

Comment: I'm assuming  the IP would be the same IP I used to deploy the war file. I try http://[IP]:8080/[war file name ] but my browser is unable to connect.

Comment: By default it's set to run on 127.0.0.1. Try starting the server with `-b 0.0.0.0` so it listens on all IP addresses.